# String reversal without altering original string

Tags: c, string

So there seems to be a plethora of string reversal questions on here, but the specific in which I want to do it seems to not be covered.  I was doing this simply as a refresher in C serves no significant purpose.  The criteria I wanted to meet,

1.Write a function that would reverse a string

2.Would not alter the original

3.Must only take in the original string as argument

4.Would not use an existing string reverse function

I initially wrote the simple code to do the reversal, but have had difficulty making it not alter the original.  Initial code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char *reverse(char *inString){
    int j = 0;
    j = strlen(inString) -1;
    char temp;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<=j; i++,j--){
        temp = inString[i];
        inString[i] = inString[j];
        inString[j] = temp;
    }
    return inString;
}


int main(){
    char string[20]="hello world";
    printf("%s\n",string);
    char *outString = reverse(string);
    printf("%s\n",string);
    printf("%s\n",outString);
}
```

Output:

```
hello world
dlrow olleh
dlrow olleh
```

Comment: `reverse(strdup(string))` or `inString = strdup(inString)` at the top of `reverse`

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two: that is too easy (http://codepad.org/ZDELCUzP) :D ;)

Comment: haha yeah, was definitely over complicating it.

Comment: Also don't forget to free the string. Also also add `return 0;` to the end of `main`

Comment: To insure `reverse` does not alter the original, add `const` --> `char *reverse(const char *inString)`.  Now the body of `reverse()` needs changing. too.

Comment: I actually just added the const right before you said that.  Should have had it in there initially though. ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion:

1. Allocate memory for a new string.
2. Fill the new string that contains the reverse of the input string.
3. Return the new string.
4. Make sure to deallocate memory of the new string in the calling function.

Something like:

```
char *reverse(char *inString)
{
   int len = strlen(inString);
   char* retString = malloc(len+1);
   if ( retString != NULL )
   {
      for(int i = 0 ; i < len; ++i)
      {
         retString[len-1-i] = inString[i];
      }
      retString[len] = '\0';
   }
   return retString;
}
```

Comment: This was actually what I was looking to do.  Maybe I need to add a 5th criteria and rule out strdup().

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char *t = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    if ( t )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for ( ; i < n; i++ ) t[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        t[i] = '\0';
    }

    return t;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "Hello World";
    char *t = reverse( s );

    puts( s );
    puts( t );

    free( t );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
dlroW olleH
```

As you see yourself you have to allocate memory for the reversed string.

Comment: Sweet! (aside from the `* sizeof( char )` which is always `* 1`).

Answer (score 0):

string and outString are referencing the same object in memory, i.e. the "hello world" string array, that's why you get the same reversed string.

Either you copy the array and reverse the copy or you reverse the string to its original form.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're indeed modifying your input string, in the line:

```
inString[i] = inString[j];
```

You don't need to do such thing. Just set the j-th char of the output string, after malloc-ing its proper space in memory.